# How to migrate Schema to ISchema in aws cdk 2.61.1

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, schema, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

Hi since the new aws cdk version (2.61.1) the Schema does no longer exist :/
So it's now impossible to import it from appsync:

`import { Schema } from "@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha"`

Vscode suggest me to use ISchema instead :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync.ISchema.html

So i try to use SchemaFile but i didn't manage to reproduce my previous comportment

```js
const apiSchema: SchemaFile = SchemaFile.fromAsset("../../playbook-api-schema/schema.graphql")
// const apiSchema = new Schema()
// apiSchema.addToSchema(appSyncCompatibleSchema)
```

Someone know whot to replace my old code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of `2.55`, the "code-first" schema generation functionality [was moved](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/23389) out of the CDK repo and to a separate package, [@cdklabs/awscdk-appsync-utils](https://github.com/cdklabs/awscdk-appsync-utils):

```js
import { CodeFirstSchema } from 'awscdk-appsync-utils';

const schema = new CodeFirstSchema();

schema.addType(new ObjectType('demo', {
  definition: { id: GraphqlType.id() },
}));
```

By the way, as of `2.60`, the "schema-first" [SchemaFile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appsync.SchemaFile.html) construct and the other remaining AppSync L2 constructs [were promoted](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.v2.md#2600-2023-01-11) from "alpha" to "stable".  They are now available in `aws-cdk-lib` like all stable APIs.  The `-alpha` package is deprecated.